# Install input secret into OpenShift build configuration

Tags: openshift

I have an OpenShift 3.9 build configuration `my_bc` and a secret `my_secret` of type `kubernetes.io/ssh-auth`. The secret was created like so:

```
oc create secret generic my_secret \
  --type=kubernetes.io/ssh-auth \
  --from-file=key
```

I have installed it as source secret into `my_bc`, and `oc get bc/my_bc -o yaml` reveals this spec:

```
source:
  contextDir: ...
  git:
    uri: ...
  sourceSecret:
    name: my_secret
  type: Git
```

As such, it is already effective in the sense that the OpenShift builder can pull from my private Git repository and produce an image with its Docker strategy.

I would now like to add `my_secret` also as an input secret to `my_bc`. My understanding is that this would not only allow the builder to make use of it (as source secret), but would allow other components inside the build to pick it up as well (as input secret). E.g. for the Docker strategy, it would exist in `WORKDIR`.

The [documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/dev_guide/builds/build_inputs.html#using-secrets-during-build) explains this with an example that adds the input secret when a build configuration is created:

```
oc new-build \
  openshift/nodejs-010-centos7~https://github.com/openshift/nodejs-ex.git \
  --build-secret secret-npmrc
```

Now the corresponding spec refers to the secret under `secrets` (not: `sourceSecret`), presumably because it is now an input secret (not: source secret).

```
source:
  git:
    uri: https://github.com/openshift/nodejs-ex.git
  secrets:
  - destinationDir: .
    secret:
      name: secret-npmrc
  type: Git
```

`oc set build-secret` apparently allows adding source secrets (as well as push and pull secrets -- these are for interacting with container registries) to a build configuration with command line argument `--source` (as well as `--push`/`--pull`), but what about input secrets? I did not find out yet.

So I have these questions:

1. How can I add `my_secret` as input secret to an existing build configuration such as `my_bc`?
2. Where would the input secret show up at build time , e.g. under which path could a `Dockerfile` pick up the private key that is stored in `my_secret`?

Comment: When using ``--build-secret``, you should also specify the path you want it add. Eg ``oc new-build https://github.com/openshift/ruby-hello-world --build-secret
npmrc:.npmrc``.

Comment: If editing existing config, you need to have ``destinationDir``. Run ``oc explain bc.spec.source.secrets`` to see fields.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Thx, I have tried again (see updated Q) but am still struggling to understand how one can add an input secret (`bc.spec.source.secrets`)  to an existing build configuration (i.e. w/o `oc new-build`). Do I have to `oc edit bc/my_bc`? I will try that next.

Comment: The command ``oc set build-secret --source bc/my_bc secret:my_secret`` is wrong. The argument is just the secret name. This is only used for pulling source code. If you use that actual value, the build pod will never startup as it is referencing a valid secret. Will likely complain about invalid characters.

Comment: As to ``COPY secret/my_secret my_secret``, the file wouldn't be called ``secret/my_secret``. In the ``secret`` directory, the files would be named corresponding to the names of the keys inside of the secret. Copy the whole ``secret`` directory and see what it is in it.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Re invalid character: Yes, just found out about that myself: `a DNS-1123 label must consist of ...`. I had to use the same kind of value that you suggested for `oc new-build ... --build-secret`, but that's apparently different. Anyway, I can "expose" the secret inside the container now and will write up an answer. Still wondering though: what's the reason one should specify a path for the source secret?

Comment: Where are you seeing an example that says to use a path with source secret? I haven't seen anywhere in docs that does that. Note that ``oc new-build --build-secret`` is input secret and not the same as ``oc create build-secret --input``. So use of ``build-secret`` in both is confusing.

Comment: As to adding input secrets to existing build, one would need to use ``oc patch`` to script it.

Comment: @GrahamDupleton I was referring to your earlier comment `you should also specify the path`. Also mistyped: "I tried to use the same kind ...". Mixed terminology build/source/input secret is a bit confusing IMO. Answer on its way now ...

Comment: I am trying to patch with `oc patch -n your-eng bc/tag-realworld -p '[{"op":"add", "path": "/spec/source/secrets", "value": "[{secret: {name: "secret-tag"}, destinationDir: "/sa-secret-volume"}]'` but am getting `yaml: did not find expected ',' or '}'`

Comment: figured it out i will post an answer :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This procedure now works for me (thanks to @GrahamDumpleton for his guidance):

1. leave build configuration's source secret as is for now; `get bc/my_bc -o jsonpath='{.spec.source.sourceSecret}'` reports `map[name:my_secret]` (w/o path)
2. add input secret to build configuration at `.spec.source.secrets` with YAML corresponding to `oc explain bc.spec.source.secrets`: `oc edit bc/my_bc`
3. sanity checks: `oc get bc/my_bc -o jsonpath='{.spec.source.secrets}'` reports `[map[destinationDir:secret secret:map[name:my_secret]]]`; `oc describe bc/my_bc | grep 'Source Secret:'` reports `Source Secret: my_secret` (no path) and `oc describe bc/my_bc | grep "Build Secrets:"` reports `Build Secrets: my_secret->secret`
4. access secret inside `Dockerfile` in a preliminary way: `COPY secret/ssh-privatekey secret/my_secret`, `RUN chmod 0640 secret/my_secret`; adjust `ssh-privatekey` if necessary (as suggested by `oc get secret/my_secret -o jsonpath='{.data}' | sed -ne 's/^map\[\(.*\):.*$/\1/p'`)
5. rebuild and redeploy image
6. sanity check: `oc exec -it <pod> -c my_db file /secret/my_secret` reports `/secret/my_secret: PEM RSA private key` (the image's `WORKDIR` is `/`)

Answer (score 0):

In the comments to the question it mentions to patch the BuildConfig. Here is a patch that works on v3.11.0:

```
$cat patch.json
{
    "spec": {
        "source": {
            "secrets": [
                {
                    "secret": {
                        "name": "secret-npmrc"
                    },
                    "destinationDir": "/etc"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
$ oc patch -n your-eng bc/tag-realworld -p "$(<patch.json)"
buildconfig "tag-realworld" patched
```